Access token and refresh token workflow
I recently learned about access token and refresh token, and if I correct, this is the steps of the most popular approach I found:

Client sends a request
Server response error for expired access token, client send another request to an endpoint in order to refresh token
Client retrieves new access token and retries the initial request
So basically 3 requests, and it sounds really ineffective to me. Why does server not refresh the access token right after catching the expired error? Are there any reasonable causes for the "3 requests" approach to make it so popular

